# How to insert data into table using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new with asp.net mvc and doing project about asp.net, I want to insert data but I can't run this code because parameter supplierID is null value (supplierID data have already in my table).

How can I insert these data ??

PhoneNo,MobileNo and FaxNo are data that I want to insert in my table.

Here is my code.

Model

> ```
>  public partial class GeneralInfosModel
> {
>     public int SupplierID { get; set; }        
>     public string CountryCode { get; set; }
>     public string TaxID { get; set; }       
>     public string PhoneNo { get; set; }       
>     public string MobileNo { get; set; }
>     public string FaxNo { get; set; }        
> }
> ```

Control
In control I have call supplierID from my table for query. This is problem supplierID is null.

> ```
>        public ActionResult ContactCompany(int supplierID )
>     {
>        // return View();
>         var model = _organizationRepository.GetDataBySupplierID(supplierID );
>         return View("ContactCompany", model);
>     }
>     [HttpPost]
>        public ActionResult ContactCompany(Tbl_Organization model)
>     {
>         var OrgModel = _organizationRepository.GetDataBySupplierID(model.SupplierID);
>         if (OrgModel != null)
>         {
>             OrgModel.PhoneNo = model.PhoneNo;               
>             OrgModel.MobileNo = model.MobileNo;                
>             OrgModel.FaxNo = model.FaxNo;               
>             _organizationRepository.Update(OrgModel);
>         }
>         var Orgmodel = _organizationRepository.GetDataBySupplierID(model.SupplierID);
>         return View("ContactCompany", Orgmodel);
>     }
> ```

View

> ```
> @using (Html.BeginForm("ContactCompany", "ContactInformation", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SupplierID" }))
> ```
>
> {

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <input type="submit" value="@T("_Global.BtnSave")" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="disablePageForm();" />
            <div style="padding-top:40px;">
            </div>
     @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.SupplierID)                
            <div class="form-inline-element margin-none" style="width: 15%;">
                @Html.Label("", T("Phone No. ").ToString(), new { @class = "captionStyle1" })
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="editorContainer">

                    @Html.DevExpress().TextBox( settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = "PhoneNumBox";
                settings.Width = 170;
               settings.Properties.NullText = "Enter your Phone Number";
            }
        ).GetHtml()
                </div>
            </div>



            <div style="padding-top:40px;">
            </div>

            <div class="form-inline-element margin-none" style="width: 15%;">
                @Html.Label("", T("Mobile Number ").ToString(), new { @class = "captionStyle1" })
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="editorContainer">
                    @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(
            settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = "MobileNumBox";
                settings.Width = 170;
                settings.Properties.NullText = "Enter your Mobile Number";
            }
        ).GetHtml()
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="padding-top:40px;">
            </div>

            <div class="form-inline-element margin-none" style="width: 15%;">
                @Html.Label("", T("Fax Number ").ToString(), new { @class = "captionStyle1" })
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="editorContainer">
                    @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(
            settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = "FaxNumBox";
                settings.Width = 170;
                settings.Properties.NullText = "Enter your Fax Number";
            }
        ).GetHtml()
                </div>
            </div>




        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Comment: Watch for capital letters, `SupplierID` is different from `supplierID`. What you're sending in the view isn't the same you're receiving in the controller

Comment: your error is here        public ActionResult ContactCompany(int supplierID )
parameters int cannot be null, you should  change to 
 public ActionResult ContactCompany(int? supplierID )

Comment: and i'll compile your code, but  this parameter int supplierID in your ActionResult is coming  from anywhere else??  i'm think that in other place in your code you have somethin like this @Html.ActionLink("Contact Company", "ContactCompany", "YourController") or maybe is an ajaxcall? i don't know but if you have it make sure to pass the id something like this <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Company", "ContactCompany", "Home", null, new { supplierID  = 54})</li>

Comment: Thank you to all comment. Now I can fix this.
I just make session for get supplierID then It can compile normally.